# gdm and fluxbox on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gdm, fluxbox

unable to run fluxbox with below package installation on ubuntu 14.04. I have mini iso installed ubuntu 14.04 running on embedded board. I am trying to configure fluxbox with below minimal package installation.

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg gdm fluxbox
reboot
```

> unable to get fluxbox, xserver/xorg session

what is missing, any ideas?

Comment: What's the real error message?

Comment: Able to get GUI, which is already logged. After logging out unable to get login GUI Window.